# ng-style not getting applied in case of dynamically added html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-style

I have a form in which fields get added dynamically upon a button click.
This is the function which adds the form fields

```
$scope.addFormField = function(){
    let container = document.getElementById('formFieldContainer');
    // a variable which keeps track of the number of fields added
    $scope.obj.fieldCount++;
    let formField = '<md-input-container><label>Mobile Number</label><input type="text" required name="mobileNo_' + $scope.obj.fieldCount + '" ng-model="obj.mobileNumberArr[' + $scope.obj.fieldCount +']" ng-pattern="/^[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$/" ng-style="form.mobileNo_' + $scope.obj.fieldCount + '.$valid ? {\'border-color\': \'green\',\'color\': \'green\'}:0"></md-input-container>';
    container.appendChild($compile(formField)($scope)[0]);
}
```

If I write the form field code directly in html, the ng-style gets applied correctly. But, if I use the above function to add form fields, the ng-style does not get applied.

Is there anything else that I should be adding to my code in order to get ng-style to work in dynamically added fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `ng-style` content in a variable and then use it in the *formField*:

```
$scope.addFormField = function(){
    let container = document.getElementById('formFieldContainer');

    // SET VARIABLE BASED ON CONDITION
    let newstyle = condition ? "{\'border-color\': \'green\',\'color\': \'green\'}" : 0;

    // a variable which keeps track of the number of fields added
    $scope.obj.fieldCount++;
    let formField = '<md-input-container><label>Mobile Number</label><input type="text" required name="mobileNo_' + $scope.obj.fieldCount + '" ng-model="obj.mobileNumberArr[' + $scope.obj.fieldCount +']" ng-pattern="/^[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$/" ng-style="' + newstyle + '"></md-input-container>';
    container.appendChild($compile(formField)($scope)[0]);
}
```

Check a demo : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9wnyusb8/18/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using a variable solved my problem. But, do you have any idea why the strategy that I was using earlier didn't work?

Comment: It seems that angular doesn't recompile the dynamically added html string, in order to evaluate the ternary expression